# Python Sqlite3 Library Ignoring 'HAVING' clause

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a script that finds the level corresponding to the first percentage greater than 0.4.

For example, consider the table:

[image]

Running, using SQLite Manager Extension for Firefox,

```
SELECT source, receiver, level FROM results WHERE percentage > 0.4 GROUP BY source,   receiver HAVING percentage = min(percentage)
```

results in the data I want:

[image]

But, when I run the following Python script

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM results"
print "Executing", sql
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
    print row

sql = ("SELECT source, receiver, level FROM results WHERE percentage > 0.4 "
        "GROUP BY source, receiver HAVING percentage = min(percentage)")
print "Executing", sql
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
    print row
    
sql = ("SELECT * FROM ("
       "SELECT source, receiver, level "
       "FROM results WHERE percentage > 0.4 ORDER BY percentage DESC)"
       "GROUP BY source, receiver")
print "Executing", sql
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
    print row
print "Done!"
```

I get the following output:

```
Executing SELECT * FROM results
(u'S1', u'R1', 10, 0.1)
(u'S1', u'R1', 11, 0.5)
(u'S1', u'R1', 12, 0.6)
(u'S2', u'R1', 10, 0.2)
(u'S2', u'R1', 11, 0.3)
(u'S2', u'R1', 12, 0.5)
(u'S2', u'R1', 13, 1)
(u'S1', u'R1', 13, 1)
Executing SELECT source, receiver, level FROM results WHERE percentage > 0.4 GROUP BY source, receiver HAVING percentage = min(percentage)
Executing SELECT * FROM (SELECT source, receiver, level FROM results WHERE percentage > 0.4     ORDER BY percentage DESC) GROUP BY source, receiver
(u'S1', u'R1', 11)
(u'S2', u'R1', 12)
Done!
```

It can be seen that the same query that was executed in SQLite Manager returns no rows.

I've included a work around, with the expected results, in the third query.

I'm using Windows 7.1 32 bit, running Python build from the Anaconda distribution:

```
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:41:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Any idea on what could be causing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using GROUP BY, you get one output row for each group.

In the SELECT and HAVING clauses, you are using values from that output row.
This means that you can use only columns from the GROUP BY clause (which have the same value in each source row of the group) or the results of aggregate functions (like `min(percentage)`).
If you use any other column, you get the value from some random row.

In this case, `level` and `percentage` come from some random row in the group.
This makes the `percentage = min(percentage)` comparison fail in some cases.

---

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, using `min()` or `max()` in the SELECT clause guarantees that the values of other columns come from the source row that matched the `min`/`max`:

```sql
SELECT source, receiver, level, min(percentage)
FROM results
WHERE percentage > 0.4
GROUP BY source, receiver
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I'm just wondering why it works in SQLite Manager and not Python?  The use case for this statement is to insert the data into another table.  In the real dataset I was using, it was inserting approximately 10 rows, but with the wrong data.  I can see now that the wrong data was due to the reasons mentioned in your answer.  I guess the differences between Python and SQLite Manager might be different versions of SQLite.